# How to dynamically change the openURL implementation in my app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, openurl

In my app, I have implemented a private method in my `AppDelegate` to override the default `openURL:` method in order to open links inside my app within `UIWebView`. But now I need the default functionalities in place too.

Here's what I did:

```
@implementation UIApplication (Private)

- (BOOL)customOpenURL:(NSURL*)url
{ 
    AppDelegate *MyWatcher = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if (MyWatcher.currentViewController) {
        [MyWatcher.currentViewController handleURL:url];
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

@end

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {  
    Method customOpenUrl = class_getInstanceMethod([UIApplication class], @selector(customOpenURL:));
    Method openUrl = class_getInstanceMethod([UIApplication class], @selector(openURL:));

   method_exchangeImplementations(openUrl, customOpenUrl);  
}
```

I also implemented `handleURL:` in my class where the custom open URL handling was needed. However, this is hindering my other class in which I just want to do a simple open of an iTunes link in iTunes. So what I don't know how to achieve is how to use the original `openURL:` in place of `customOpenURL:`.

Comment: why can't you just call `customOpenURL` instead of `openURL`? No need for overriding then.

Comment: Because customURL will open the link in UIWebView but for one link i want it open in UIwebView and for the other one i want it to be open with iTunes.

Comment: But I wonder, why you can't call `customOpenURL` for the link you want to open in `UIWebView` and `openURL` for the one you want to launch externally in iTunes?

Comment: because i m doing this in appdelegate:Method customOpenUrl = class_getInstanceMethod([UIApplication class], @selector(customOpenURL:));
    Method openUrl = class_getInstanceMethod([UIApplication class], @selector(openURL:));

   method_exchangeImplementations(openUrl, customOpenUrl);

Comment: Yep, I know, but I was wondering why are you doing that method exchange. Anyway, see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just subclass `UIApplication` and override `openURL:` directly. Be sure to change the principle class in your `Info.plist` to use your `UIApplication` subclass.

Example:

```
@interface ECApplication : UIApplication

@end

@implementation ECApplication

- (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url
{

    AppDelegate *MyWatcher = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if (MyWatcher.currentViewController) {
        [MyWatcher.currentViewController handleURL:url];
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

@end
```

Then, in your `Info.plist` file, look for the Principle Class key, and change the value to `ECApplication` (or whatever you name your subclass).

Comment: And from appdelegate should i remove the private implementation of UIApplication. But now as the principal class will be ECApplication how will the openURL method would work

Comment: Yes, remove the category on `UIApplication`. Using this setup, everything should work normally in `UIApplication` except your custom `openURL:` method will be used.

Comment: I did the same thing you said but now when i say openURL for the url which i want to open in iTunes it also goes to this subclass.

Comment: And as the condition is still true it calls the handleURL method again.

Comment: If you wan't to access the original implementation of `openURL:` you can just call `[super openURL:url];` from anywhere in your custom `openURL:` method.

Comment: @edc1591 If you're around today I'd like to pick your brain about this. I realize this thread is fairly old now, but nevertheless...

Comment: @MilesAlden Sure, feel free to shoot me an email evan at evancoleman.net

Answer (score 2):

You can set the original implementation to some other method and then just call it:

```
@implementation UIApplication (Private)
- (BOOL)originalOpenURL:(NSURL*)url 
{
     return NO;
}

- (BOOL)customOpenURL:(NSURL*)url
{
     if (/* some condition */)
     {
        // your code
     }
     else
     {
        return [self originalOpenURL: url];
     }
}

@end

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {  
     Method customOpenUrl = class_getInstanceMethod([UIApplication class], @selector(customOpenURL:));
     Method openUrl = class_getInstanceMethod([UIApplication class], @selector(openURL:));
     Method originalOpenUrl = class_getInstanceMethod([UIApplication class], @selector(originalOpenURL:));

     method_exchangeImplementations(openUrl, originalOpenUrl); 
     method_exchangeImplementations(openUrl, customOpenUrl);  
}
```

*Note:* This is just a solution giving direct answer to your question. The clearer approach to this problem is the one suggested by @edc1591. You can access original `openURL:` with `[super openURL:url]`.

Comment: Not working either. I think i am going to try the one given by edc and come back.

Comment: Where should i do this [super openURL:url];

Comment: @Ashutosh it does work - just tested in my Xcode and iPhone simulator.

Answer (score 0):

The approach pointed out by Krizz works on the first app launch only, if you happen to open an URL that redirects you to another App (i.e.: Facebook app), it messes with the implementations when your app is resumed. Adding a flag to make sure the method_exchangeImplementations is called only on the first app launch seems to work.